# How can I fit x-axis labels according with its bar?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, ios-charts

I am using `ios-chart` library and I have a `CombinedBarChart` in which I made zoom on it by default

```
combinedBarChart.setScaleMinima(2, scaleY: 1)
combinedBarChart.setScaleEnabled(false)
```

I would like that each x-axis label will stay above each bar but I cannot make it work properly.

Here is my example:

[image]

As you can see, x-axis labels does not correspond with their bars respectively.

How can I make that each x-axis label will be above of its bar?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you set BarWidth property in your ChartData ?

Comment: @CodeChanger No, I only have used `setScaleMinima` to scale the Chart.

Comment: Can you show an image of what you want to accomplish?

Comment: @DevB2F I would like that on top of bar 1 will be January, on top of bar 2 February, on top of bar 3 March and so on... You can see that June is not exactly on the top of bar 5.

Comment: Can you show me the full code? Then I can run it and fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was not able to reproduce the problem by adding this to my combinedChart:

```
 combinedBarChart.setScaleMinima(2, scaleY: 1)
 combinedBarChart.setScaleEnabled(false)
```

But until you upload your code, I can suggest the following:

1. Make sure

   ```
   combinedBarChart.xAxis.granularity = 1
   ```

2.
Shift the graph a bit to the left.

```
    var shift = -0.2
    var entries: [BarChartDataEntry] = []
    for index in 0..<datapoints.count {
       let value1 = Double(datapoints[index])
       let value2 = Double(datapoints[index])
       entries.append(BarChartDataEntry(x: Double(index)+shift, yValues: [value1, value2]))
    }
```

3. By lowering the number of bars shown on each screen, you create more space between bars and that might solve the problem:

   ```
    combinedBarChart.setVisibleXRange(minXRange: 4.0, maxXRange: 4.0)
   ```
4. You might also want to change all the month names to a 3 digit name, like Jan, Feb, Mar, ... to see if that makes the problem go away. 
   If it does, and you don´t want to use 3 digit names, you can add white spaces at the end of the month names to make them all equally long. Like "January  ", "February ", "March    ", "August   ", "September",    "October  ", "December ".

Comment: Thank you! Using `combinedBarChart.xAxis.granularity = 1` was enough to make it work properly :)